# How to do large-scale texture painting?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I am making a large open-world video game and the terrain I am using is made from a mesh generated with the A.N.T. landscape generator plugin. The mesh itself is scaled to about 20 sq. km in area. (I already unwrapped the mesh for anyone asking.) I want to apply textures to it with texture painting to get a decent appearance, but the mesh is so large I'd have to use a couple hundred-thousand-pixel base texture to get a crisp texturing job (any lower and the textures will get very disproportionally large and blurry). I think there is a way to do this by dividing the mesh up into several chunks so I could use several smaller textures instead of a much larger and unweildly one to get a crisp job done, but that would take me way too much time as I'd have to divide it into 64+ chunks for this to be viable. So I'd like to see if I can get a good texturing result without doing this or (if I have to split up the mesh) a tool that could automate that action. Thanks to anyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this works in your project but if I would create a landscape I would use seamless textures for every material that you want to use, then paint a mask where witch material should be.

You can paint the mask in a very low resolution but the actual environment uses sharp textures.

Comment: This has worked for me, thank you! Turns out there's a scale option  (Textures Tab > Mapping > Size) with the textures so I can work knowing I'll get crisp images. Thanks!!